# How to create a sfx with progressbar by sevenzipsharp in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, 7zip, sfx, sevenzipsharp

I want to create a sfx file with C# WinForms.
I have downloaded sevensharp from https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com .
I could not get any step by step tutorial for this.
Some similar question I got from stackoverflow and other site, but all didn't work and showing error.
I want to add custom from in the sfx, when user double click the "File_sfx.exe" then the custom form will be shown and ask for password.

I added **"SevenZipSfx.cs"** as a class, **"SevenZipSharp.dll"** as a reference, and copied **"7z.dll"** to the output folder of Visual Studio.

Sample Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath("7z.dll");
        SevenZipCompressor sevenZipCompressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
        sevenZipCompressor.CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.Ultra;
        sevenZipCompressor.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Lzma;

        SevenZipSfx compressor = new SevenZipSfx("7z.sfx");
        compressor.MakeSfx(@"E:\cm1.7z", @"E:\cm1.exe");

    }
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample code and the error you are receiving?

Comment: @Nimesh, yeah, please see the new edited version. The file exists but it is telling the file does not exists. I cross checked the file name and past, were 100% correct.

Comment: whats z1.exe referred in the exception?

Comment: @Nimesh, z1.exe is the MainForm that has button2.

Comment: DId you checled this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069470/how-to-create-a-compressed-sfx-file-using-sevenzipsharp?rq=1) from related links, seems to be similar issue

Comment: @Nimesh, I have checked, not work, and also in VB. I converted into C# but same issue.